# Call a LESS mixin by variable name

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

just a short question.
Is it possible to call a mixin by a variable name?

Example:

```
.for(@special-units); .-each(@value) {
    &.f-@{value} {           
         //call a mixin which has the same name like @value
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, you can't call a mixin like that.

Comment: I'd suggest you to provide an example of *what* you're trying to achieve instead of *how* you think you could do that. (Usually a request for such feature hints of missing the notion of parametric mixins).